# Configure binary to require sudo

Tags: sudo, security, system, system-settings

I want to restrict all users who can run traceroute to the sudo group on my system. What's a way to enforce this requirement for all users?

Instead of being able to use
`traceroute google.com`, I want users to write `sudo traceroute google.com`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the execute permission for other on the binary.

```
sudo chmod 750 /usr/sbin/traceroute
```

Note that this will not stop users from discovering routes by copying the traceroute binary to their home directory, or for instance write their own using python. You should *not* rely on this for security in any way.

Comment: In my notebook, I wrote a short sudoer rule. Still looking for other options until posting mine. I'm not really convinced yet that this is the best method, but I think it's not incorrect. :)
`%users  !/usr/sbin/traceroute`

Comment: Users that are not member of `sudo` group cannot use sudo by default. What are you attempting to achieve?

Comment: Restrict usage to only sudo group.

Comment: A sudo rule won't help you with that. `traceroute` does not require any special permissions to run. Also note, as I wrote in the answer, that this is *not* a security measure by itself. Any determined user can detect routes selected if they want, even if you disable the `traceroute` command.

Comment: Ok, but if users cannot access shell or build their own program, how would they trace routes otherwise? I think you're working on the assumption this is for security.

Comment: I'm wondering what you're trying to achieve, and why. This is somewhat essential to answering in a good way... My answer will work perfectly; any user without root permissions ins ome fashion will *not* be able to run the command...